# Best data organistion in cosmos DB (or other document db)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have to save many items for different users in the Cosmos DB - so a single user can have multiple items. I would later display those items for selected user or display all items for all users. Should I create a collection for each user or maybe a single collection for all items with some user tag in the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a single collection for all users, you can choose the userid as a **partition key** and queries running in a single or few selected partitions will run great. For queries to report on all users, a "fan out" query will be expensive for [RU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units) ( resource units). Here you have two options.

One - if your fan out is rarely run - scale up your Cosmosdb account, run the query and then scale it down.

The other and preferred solution  is to use  [change feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#use-cases) where you maintain a separate collection for the "all user" information thus saving on your RU.

On the other hand if you create multiple collections - each for separate user - you would still need to have a partition key for those collections and from the total RU perspective this may be more expensive as there are minimum RUs.

In short, you are better off using a single collection, partition by userid, use change feed. And if you have other collections - you can share RU across them in the same [database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#set-throughput-on-a-database)

Hope this helps.